# Monogame and MonoDevelop missing IDE MacOSX

Tags: installation, monogame

I tried installing monogame and monodevelop but after downloading and installing the required applications there is no Monogame IDE in my application folder.

What i did was the following: 
Started on the monogame download page (http://www.monogame.net/downloads) and followed the corresponding links to download these files for OSX:

- Xamarin Studio 4.0.12 installer
- Mono + GTK#  to which it linked me to the mono download page to which i download
- The Runtime and SDK files for OSX Version 2.10.x

I installed each program in the corresponding order and continues the installation process by downloading the MonoGame installation V3.0.1 for Xamarin and MonoDevelop because i wasnt sure which one to get. But when I couldn't simply drag or click to install I looked in my application folder there was no Monogame IDE only the Xamarin Studio IDE which I presume is the correct process. But When I opened the Xamarin IDE it says that I've download the starter version and I cannot use Monogame.

Aside from the monogame website and various googling instructions, I've tried following these very clear instruction from this blog (http://mastrgamr.net/xna/programming-xna-on-mac/) but got stuck when I could find nor open my MonoGame and the Xamarian IDE displaying the correct screen.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong as the installation instructions seem very clear.

EDIT: 
So i found out that Xamarian IDE replaced the MonoDeveloper IDE though the instructions I've found are using MonoDeveloper IDE as the example. I'm not sure if theres a significant difference but I presume there is a difference as I still can't seem to run monoGame and the outdated instructions aren't syncretic with my actions. Can anyone provide me with updated Xamarian instructions?

Answer (score 0):

A little while ago [Xamarin replaced MonoDevelop with Xamarin Studio](http://blog.xamarin.com/the-making-of-xamarin-studio/). So MonoDevelop is now called Xamarin Studio and it looks and behaves a little different. That's why any tutorials talking about MonoDevelop are going to be a little confusing.

I've never tried to install Xamarin Studio on a Mac so I'm not sure what the error is about the starter version. However, I suspect it might be talking about the [Xamarin licensing](https://store.xamarin.com/).

What I can tell you is, you won't be able to develop games with MonoGame on the starter edition if you are targeting platforms other than Windows (this includes Android, iOS and I presume Mac) due to the limited app size. You should consider buying a license from Xamarin if this is indeed your issue.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I'm fine with the starter licence as I don't plan to release any games rather I just want to be able to use XNA on my mac for practice for a uni subject. I tried running windows on a virtual machine but XNA is not compatible as it need direct X10 and VMWare only emulates X9.

Comment: MonoGame also has a Windows OpenGL version you can run. I'm not sure how well it will work on VMWare though. Good luck.